# SQL: get a negative value

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a sql like this:

```
SELECT  PRODUCTID, UCASE(MYTYPE) AS MYTYPE, UNIT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'ADD' THEN REORDER_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS IN_QTY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'DEDUCT' THEN REORDER_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS OUT_QTY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'ADD' THEN REORDER_QTY
                WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'DEDUCT' THEN - REORDER_QTY
                ELSE 0
           END) AS TOTAL_BALANCE_QTY
FROM INVENTORY_HISTORY
GROUP BY PRODUCTID
ORDER BY MYTYPE ASC
```

it work fine until i add where clause like this:

```
WHERE STOREID='6' AND ENTERED_DATE BETWEEN '2014-09-15' AND '2014-09-30'
```

Problem:

i will get negative value for **TOTAL_BALANCE_QTY** because it sum all the **IN_QTY** and deduct the **OUT_QTY**, but the total of **IN_QTY** is less than **OUT_QTY**. How do i avoid the negative value? without where clause, i got no issue, because it sum all the IN_QTY from beginning of time. any suggestion?

[image]

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory_history` (
  `INVHID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `INVENTORYID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STOREID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRODUCTID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNIT` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QTY_BALANCE` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNIT_PRICE` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REORDER_QTY` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MYTYPE` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADJUST_TYPE` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRANSC_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTERED_BY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTERED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_BY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MODIFIED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`INVHID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2142 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

SQL data: [Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ivhojwjky8rmlg/invenotry_history.sql?dl=0) (not able to put to sqlfiddle due to char 8000 limit)

Any suggestion/help would be great.

Comment: what do you want to do? have it be 0 if its a negative number?

Comment: yes can it be 0 for negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PRODUCTID, MYTYPE, UNIT, IN_QTY, OUT_QTY, IF(TOTAL_BALANCE_QTY < 0, 0.00, TOTAL_BALANCE_QTY) AS TOTAL_BALANCE_QTY
FROM
(    SELECT PRODUCTID, UCASE(MYTYPE) AS MYTYPE, UNIT,
            SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'ADD' THEN REORDER_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS IN_QTY,
            SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'DEDUCT' THEN REORDER_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS OUT_QTY,
            SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'ADD' THEN REORDER_QTY
                     WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'DEDUCT' THEN - REORDER_QTY
                     ELSE 0
                END
            ) AS TOTAL_BALANCE_QTY
    FROM INVENTORY_HISTORY
    GROUP BY PRODUCTID
    ORDER BY MYTYPE ASC
)temp
```

a better working example would be to use GREATEST() with a default value so you dont need the outer query

```
SELECT PRODUCTID, UCASE(MYTYPE) AS MYTYPE, UNIT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'ADD' THEN REORDER_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS IN_QTY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'DEDUCT' THEN REORDER_QTY ELSE 0 END) AS OUT_QTY,
       GREATEST(SUM(CASE WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'ADD' THEN REORDER_QTY
                         WHEN ADJUST_TYPE = 'DEDUCT' THEN - REORDER_QTY
                         ELSE 0
                    END), 0
       ) AS TOTAL_BALANCE_QTY
FROM INVENTORY_HISTORY
GROUP BY PRODUCTID
ORDER BY MYTYPE ASC
```

Comment: this works, thanks. Crazy user dont want to see negative value.

Comment: @David sure thing :) i may be able to work up a better answer.. but if you could mark it as accepted it would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: marked, if you have better solution do let me know too :)

Comment: that is just awesome :) how does GREATEST understand its need 0? however, i get the logic for: IF(TOTAL_BALANCE_QTY < 0

Comment: @David think of it this way.. `SELECT GREATEST(15,10,25)` will return 25 as the greatest value... so if you do a value aka your sum... and then 0 it will return the greatest of the two.. so if its negative it'll return the 0.. you can also make it 0.00 if you prefer :) -- greatest returns the greatest value of whatever is passed.. so with two params `GREATEST(SUM(CASE...), 0)` will return your sum when its greater than 0 or else it'll return 0 when its negative

Comment: that is a nice trick, think out of a box, you are good, thanks for the explanation and solution :)